# Is pitot and static pressure brought up to cockpit of Antonov 225 for the instruments?

Tags: antonov-225

Onboard the Antonov An-225, was the pitot and static pressure brought to the cockpit for the instruments such as airspeed indicators etc,. Or did the An-225 use remote indication through the use of transmitters?

Answer (score 1):

Like all large modern aircraft of that era, pitot and static pressure will have been fed to an air data computer. The information is then distributed electrically to the flight instruments.